# Elasticsearch Span_near with bool query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I need to find out all documents that have the words **"London"** or **"Gucci"** or **"fashion"**. But at the same time I wan't all those documents that have all or some of these 3 words (all or 2 or 1) then they should be boosted in score based on their proximity..  i.e.,

1. Doc A - "London is big. Gucci is brand".
2. Doc B - "London is big".
3. Doc C - "Gucci is a fashion brand in London".
4. Doc D - "Gucci fashion show in London".

**Result should be in order -**

1. Doc D (all 3 words exist, with 2 words together, 1 separate)
2. Doc C (all 3 words exist, with each of them separate)
3. Doc A (2 words exist, with each of them separate)
4. Doc B (1 word exist)

I'm trying the following search -

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "query_string": {
                    "default_field": "transcription",
                    "query": "\"Gucci\" OR \"Chinese\" OR \"London\""
                }
            },
            {
                "span_near": {
                    "clauses": [
                        {
                            "span_term": {
                                "transcription": "Gucci"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "span_term": {
                                "transcription": "Chinese"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "span_term": {
                                "transcription": "London"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "boost": 10,
                    "slop": 50,
                    "in_order": false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"highlight": {
    "fields": {
        "transcription": {
            "type": "plain"
        }
    }
}}
```

But I'm only getting results according to query_string . Seems like span_near is not working.. i.e., Documents are not being boosted based on proximity.

What is wrong here ?

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to your question?